# Progress amount format in PDF

Tags: format, openedge, progress-4gl

I want to show amount like this format `100,000,000.00`. In my code i defined variable like this 
`DEFINE VARIABLE mAMOUNT  AS INTEGER FORMAT "999,999,999,999,99.99".`
 and `mAMOUNT = 100,000,000.00`and how ever i got amount like this `100000000` Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

```
define variable amount as decimal ">>>,>>>,>>>,>>9.99" no-undo.

amount = 123456789.01.

display amount.
```

"9" in a FORMAT phrase forces a digit to be shown -- you might have an "all 9s" format if you wanted leading zeros but that is unusual.

If you intend to have decimal places you need to use the DECIMAL datatype, not INTEGER.